# Reusing XML in android by <include>

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-tabhost

I am using `ActionBarSherlock` for tabs in android

**main_fragment_desc_list_view.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <include layout="@layout/screen_parent_topbar" />

    <android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>

    <include layout="@layout/screen_parent_bottombar" />

</LinearLayout>
```

---

**What i am having trouble with ?**

Even though i have added the code  `<include layout="@layout/screen_parent_bottombar" />` it is not shown in the screen when i execute the code

[image]

**What changes should i need to make here so that i am able to get my bottom layout included at the bottom ?**

Comment: post the xml for screen_parent_bottombar

Comment: XML is correct .... because even if i refer `<include layout="@layout/screen_parent_topbar" />` in botton again still its not displayed

Comment: try setting the layout params for the include

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost` has a height of MATCH_PARENT and therefore the layout at the bottom will not appear.

One alternative would be using a RelativeLayout to create the header/content/footer layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <include android:id="@+id/header"
             android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
             layout="@layout/screen_parent_topbar" />

    <include android:id="@+id/footer"
             android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
             layout="@layout/screen_parent_bottombar" />

    <android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
        android:layout_below="@id/header"
        android:layout_above="@id/footer"
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>


</RelativeLayout>
```